# Is redirecting a 404 error page to the front page possible?

Tags: 8, redirection

Is it possible to redirect all the pages returning a 404 error to the front page?

I am not sure the new Drupal 8 *Redirect* module (which combines the  Drupal 7 version of the *Global redirect* and the *Redirect* modules) would help me to achieve this exact task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to the Basic Site Settings (/admin/config/system/site-information) and enter in "/" for the default 404 (not found) page does that work for you?

[image]

Comment: This doesn't perform a redirect, it simply displays the homepage  while incorrect path would still be in the address bar. For e.g. /nosuch/page would say you are viewing a page at that path while displaying the homepage. The purpose of these settings is so you can show "404 - try these option". A homepage is not a "404" page.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of points from my system (Drupal8/ELB w/https)

1) Core Option - The core option only gives limited success

```
/admin/config/system/site-information
```

2) Community module - Better option seemed to be 'Redirect':

```
https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect
```

3) HTACCESS - if you have certain matches etc (eg. .asp/.aspx) :
add something like this to .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 301 "\.asp(.*)$"  /
```